# Is there any function in R that gives the labels inside the circles of a scatter plot?

Tags: r

Im trying to create a scatter plot with labels embedded inside the circles with ggplot. Is there any function to label inside the circles??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Swetha. What have you done so far? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hey Swetha, welcome to SO! Can you share how your expected graph should look like (a hand drawing will work)? Are the labels numeric? Because text labels inside circles may not be legible.

Comment: Yes the labels are numeric. In ggplot2, the geom_label command worked. Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

If you want text inside circles, just draw the circles then draw the text in the same place:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = runif(26), y = runif(26), z = LETTERS)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, label = z)) +
  geom_point(size = 10, shape = 21, fill = "white") +
  geom_text(vjust = 0.4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about `geom_label()` from `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)


ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, label = rownames(mtcars))) + 
  geom_label()
```

[image]